# ffmpeg pad doesn't extend background to the full width of the video

Tags: ffmpeg

We're trying to make this pad filter extend the background white color to the full width of the video while keeping the video centered, without ruining its aspect ratio. Everything we've tried didn't work.

**Current output:** [image]
**Desired output:** [image]

**Command used:**

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 0 -to 14 -i video-input.mp4 -t 14 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=878:494:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,pad=width=878:height=494:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=white,settb=expr=1/25,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -codec:v libx264 -r 25 -map [v] video.mp4
```

**Command log:**

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-1ubuntu0~20.04.sav0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu0~20.04.sav0.1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzimg --enable-crystalhd --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video-input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:14.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4029 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 878x494 [SAR 1171:3700 DAR 514069:913900], 4026 kb/s, SAR 2223:7024 DAR 9:16, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ETI ISO Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:04:47.22, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] using SAR=1171/3700
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] 264 - core 161 r3039 544c61f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 878x494 [SAR 2223:7024 DAR 9:16], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=  350 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   14022kB time=00:00:13.96 bitrate=8228.2kbits/s speed=31.9x    
video:14019kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.016606%
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] frame I:2     Avg QP:16.00  size:106657
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] frame P:348   Avg QP:20.22  size: 40638
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] mb P  I16..4: 20.6%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 65.3%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:14.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 99.0% 98.0% 89.1% inter: 63.2% 54.4% 32.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] i16 v,h,dc,p:  1% 88%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 12% 81%  2%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x55711e821b40] kb/s:8203.02
```

We've tried playing with increase/decrease or scaling to different resolutions but can't make it work. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. *"We're trying to make this pad filter extend the background white color to the full width of the video while keeping the video centered, without ruining its aspect ratio."* Your input is 878x494. The output is also 878x494. You can't pad and center if the input and output are the same size.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @llogan! It does make sense, indeed, we'll double check the input/command.